# WebResource.axd or ScriptResource.axd not found after rewrite aspx

Tags: asp.net, .net, url-rewriting, webforms, updatepanel

after rewrite aspx and remove .aspx end of file

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteASPX">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

browser show error :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) :WebResource.axd or ScriptResource.axd
```

and

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined 

__browserLink/requestData/e9a9388e7386443f9dd605019e63
```